# Laravel Eloquent delete() not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Documentation says:

```
$user = User::find($user_id);

$user->delete();
```

This doesnt work, however ProductColor::find($color_id) working. $color->delete() Doest return anything, DELETE FROM query doesn't even execute (as seen in debug bar).

But I can delete record with:

```
ProductColor::destroy($color_id);
```

Must be something I overlooked earlier, I'm new to Laravel.

I'm using store also, and it working as expected

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $color = new ProductColor();
        $color->name = $request->color_name;
        $color->order = $request->color_order;
        $saved = $color->save();

        if ($saved) {
            return back()->with('message:success', 'Ok');
        } else {
            return back()->with('message:error', 'Error');
        }

    }
```

To sum up

This WORKS

```
public function destroy($color_id)
    {
        $deleted = ProductColor::destroy($color_id);

        if ($deleted) {
            return back()->with('message:success', 'Deleted');
        } else {
            return back()->with('message:error', 'Error');
        }
    }
```

This NOT

```
public function destroy($color_id)
{
  $color = ProductColor::find($color_id);

  $color->delete();
}
```

My Model

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Shop\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Modules\Languages\Entities\Language;

class ProductColor extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $table = 'product_colors';
}
```

Comment: Really I don't know why this doesn't work. But why don't you try it with query ?? `$user = User::where('user_id', $user_id)->delete();`

Comment: My IDE showing that 'where' is not a static method, so I just used User::destroy($user_id);

Comment: What's the error when you try to use `delete()`?

Comment: As I said, no error, nothing it just not excecuting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry, I've figured out the problem. My mistake to post this question.

What I tried to do:

```
$color = new ProductColor();
$color->find($color_id);
$color->delete();
```

Should be:

```
$color = ProductColor::find( $color_id );
$color->delete();
```

My problem was that I was scared about the IDE complaining about using non-static method 'find'

Comment: The first example is fine but you'd have to assign the return value of find(), since it returns a new model, it doesn't just attach the attributes to the existing one.

Comment: You can make your IDE happier by using `Product::query()->find(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Please check your model class if you have added soft delete option in that case your record will not be deleted from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine - [the docs show exactly](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#deleting-models) what you are doing.

If there is no error, and the color is not deleted as expected, then `$color_id` is not being passed as expected.  Try using [`findOrFail`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models), or add some other check that you found the expected model.

Answer (score 1):

```
 DB::table('pykcodes')
                ->where('user_id', $user_id)
                ->delete();
```

This works directly without using the model.
Just make sure you call `use DB;` from the top.

Comment: For anybody coming across this, be aware that this will NOT fire [model events](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#events)!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was, the name of the property inside the `uri` on the routes file was incorrect:

```
Route::delete('/foo/{fo3o}', [DollyController::class, 'delete']);
                  -----^
```

I don't know why the controller method was working:

```
public function delete(Foo $foo)
{
    $foo->delete();
    return ['message' => 'success'];
}
```

After correcting it, the problem was solve and the delete method started working again:

```
Route::delete('/foo/{foo}', [DollyController::class, 'delete']);
                ------^
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What was happening was a difference between the variable i set in the route and the variable i was receiving in the delete method

For example: my route was like this

```
...
Route::resource('global', InsumoController::class);
...
```

The resource create default routes, and one of them is:

global/{global} receiving the DELETE method

In the Controller, the variable that the method destroy receive must have the name 'global'. If not, will not work;

That worked for me, maybe is something to check if you have a similar issue.

Answer (score -5):

You have to add SoftDeletes in User Model:

...

> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

> use SoftDeletes;
>
> protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

...

Comment: That would only be if you added the deleted_at column and wanted soft deletes.  If you actually wanted to delete the row, this would be a bad solution.

Comment: Right, only applicable if you have deleted_at column in your users table. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent for adding softdeletes